# Using code from github for own thesis

Tags: citations, authorship, code

For my master thesis I should write a simulation program, and compare the results with the results I get from commercial programs. Now I found a already existing script with exact the data I need on github which does all the background work for me, and I can modify it for my specific purposes. The script is already based on a public available script.
My approach would have be the same, but I would have needed some time to bring it to this extent. Now I am not sure how I can use this script in my thesis: Can I use it (github does not allow PMs to ask the author this question), and how should I cite it? I know that I have to cite the author in my literature appendix in each case, but how far do I have to mark my changings in the code?

Comment: You could file an issue report asking the author the question.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the license on the code permits it there's nothing wrong with using open source code in your thesis. If the license is an open-source style license which allows derivative works you don't even need to contact the author for permission though it may be polite to do so.

How it should be cited depends on the citations style your thesis is to be written with but has come up before on the site.

[How do you cite a Github repository?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14010/how-do-you-cite-a-github-repository)

In general you're golden as long as you make it extremely clear that your work is an extension of existing code and make it extremely clear what the source is. If this is central to your thesis then I'd mention it prominently in the text rather than simply listing it as a citation.

If it's academic/scientific code there may be documentation on the authors site specifying what publication should be cited in relation to the code .

If you want to show exactly what you've done yourself you can generate a file listing all the changed/added/removed lines which you can attach as an appendix.

I did almost exactly this as part of my MSc: taking an open source tool and adding extra functionality to it then publishing it with changes.

Edit: if there's no license then you'll need to get in contact with the author somehow. This may help.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12687679/3535153

Comment: There is no license available on the readme, the readme itself is not even finished. The author itself also has no own web page which could cite it. The contribution to my thesis is ~20% saved work.

Comment: @arc_lupus if there's no license then you'll need to get in contact with the author somehow. This may help.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12687679/3535153

Comment: Tested it, user used a non-reachable mail for his repos...

Comment: From Github's help page: `Generally speaking, the absence of a license means that the default copyright laws apply.` But also, by that user posting it on Github he has accepted their ToS which means: `specifically, you allow others to view and fork your repository.`

Comment: Expanding on @AustinHenley's comment, "default copyright laws" essentially say you have *no* permission from the author to do anything with the work. You will have to get in touch with them somehow.

Comment: @vonbrand But you are allowed to fork it which seems like it is a bit of a gray area.

Comment: @AustinHenley, OP should definitely ask the github people and perhaps somebody knowledgeable in law about this. There *probably* is no problem, the authors will *probably* be thrilled to learn that the stuff was used (you should think of telling them, and at least open a new repo with your changes or ask them to pull them); but then again, whoever put this on github might not be allowed to do so...