# How do I cite this 3D teapot model in my BibTeX file?

Tags: citations, data, bibtex

I am working on some data transformations that work in finite dimensions. To help motivate the reader I would like a simple, but not too simple, example to show how the transformations work. A [3D teapot](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/3d-teapot/971436783?qa_expand_key=ag5zfmtoYW4tYWNhZGVteXJCCxIIVXNlckRhdGEiJXVzZXJfZW1haWxfa2V5X2subi5ibHVlc3RhckBnbWFpbC5jb20MCxIIRmVlZGJhY2sYmXUM) is available on Khan Academy that would suite the purpose nicely (one might even say it was my [cup of tea](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cup%20of%20tea), but I don't drink right out of the pot!). I see that it is the intellectual property of user [Peter Collingridge](https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_1128810778687926889052316) under an [Attribution 4.0 International (CC BY 4.0)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) license, so I do not see why I could not use it provided that I give credit.

What should go into my BibTeX entry within my `*.bib` file for something like this?

---

What I have put together so far:

```
@misc{
    title = {3D Teapot [Data Set]},
    howpublished = {https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/3d-teapot/971436783?qa_expand_key=ag5zfmtoYW4tYWNhZGVteXJCCxIIVXNlckRhdGEiJXVzZXJfZW1haWxfa2V5X2subi5ibHVlc3RhckBnbWFpbC5jb20MCxIIRmVlZGJhY2sYmXUM},
    owner = {Peter Collingridge},
    note = {Accessed: 2022-02-21}
}
```

Comment: I found this [@dataset](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/880) entry type, which I will have to check if it is compatible with my TeX environment.

Comment: It is no different from citing any other online source, really. And there are plenty resources on the topic of citing online sources :) See if this helps, for one: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/151533/how-to-cite-a-github-repository-that-i-used-for-data-collection-research-paper/151557#151557. As for the format of the bibtex entry, that depends on the citation style. But as far as I understand, yours is not a technical question.