# What reference type to use in EndNote to cite GitHub resources and how to cite

Tags: citations, citation-style

What reference type should I use in EndNote to cite a GitHub resource? And how do I cite the resource in the fields used in EndNote for the specific reference type?

Comment: I hope this helps: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14010/how-do-you-cite-a-github-repository

Comment: Yes, I have already read this question, but I need information on how to cite a GitHub repository on EndNote. I can't seem to find anything regarding this.

Comment: Is it possible to enter the details manually?

Comment: Yes, the information can be entered manually but I still need a Reference type in EndNote to insert the information in the specific fields.

Comment: Just use 'website' or 'electronic article'. Or create your own ref type: https://support.clarivate.com/Endnote/s/article/EndNote-Adding-and-Changing-Reference-Types?language=en_US